# QGIS: Python script to batch clip vector layers and set their CRS

Tags: pyqgis, vector, clip, batch

Here below the sript I'm trying to run. 
clip_zone is a polygon and in my input_folder, I have a point layer and polyline layer.

```
#Tell Python where you will get processing from
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Brighton\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing')

#Reference the algorithm you want to run 
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

#Define the workspace
input_folder = "C:\Users\id846890\Documents\FAN\Design\Test_clip\input\ "
output_folder = "C:\Users\id846890\Documents\FAN\Design\Test_clip\output\ "
clip_zone = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Users\id846890\Documents\FAN\Design\Test_clip\FH.shp','FH', 'ogr')
crs=clip_zone.crs()
crs.createFromId(31370)
clip_zone.setCrs(crs)

#Clip the shapefiles 
for vectorLayer in input_folder:
    layer_clipped = os.path.join(output_folder, vectorLayer.name())
    processing.runalg('qgis:clip', vectorLayer, clip_zone, layer_clipped)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Bocquet_Wagner! Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/219346/edit) your question to include what is the problem? Do you receive errors? Is there no output (which _could_ be the problem as you're not escaping the path of your `clip_zone`, I tend to use forward slashes like `'C:/Users/id846890/Documents/FAN/Design/Test_clip/FH.shp'`)?